# Ubuntu 20.10 sssd (System Security Services Daemon) failure

Tags: 20.10, sssd

Don't know why, but they decided to add sssd (System Security Services Daemon) to the standard Ubuntu 20.10 **upgrade** and **fresh install**. It fails to start, and generates lots of error messages. It's not configured at install time, as it's missing the required /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file.

SSSD is a system daemon. Its primary function is to provide access to local or remote identity and authentication resources through a common framework that can provide caching and offline support to the system. It provides several interfaces, including NSS and PAM modules or a D-Bus interface.

You can see the failure with:

```
systemctl status sssd
```

Comment: My problem! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315875/sssd-service-ubuntu-20-04-desktop-problem

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are at least three possible fixes.

**Fix #1:**

Disable `sssd` from starting on systems where it's not needed.

```
sudo systemctl stop sssd
sudo systemctl disable sssd
```

**Fix #2:**

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/conf/sssd.conf /etc/sssd/.
sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf 
sudo systemctl enable sssd
sudo systemctl start sssd
```

Source: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2452209&p=13994052

**Fix #3:**

Properly configure sssd, using /etc/sssd/sssd.conf, to your site's specific needs. See `man sssd.conf` for more information.

Comment: In order to decide what fix to apply, have a look at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd first.

Comment: Second solution works on same issue on debian 11. I boot up with live ubunto then mount root partition copy files and reboot.