# Having SSSD problems at boot since upgrading to 20.10

Tags: boot, upgrade, ssd, 20.10, sssd

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu (Gnome) 20.10 and ever since I have lots of messages like

```
SSSD failed to start system security daemon
dependency failed for PAM security socker
... and some more dependency related info...
```

during boot. As a beginner to Ubuntu I am not well able to judge how serious this problem is. But I don't want red flagged lines during my boot and that makes that I want to eliminate this problem. In `journalctl  -b` I found some messages pertaining to to SSSD (see below). Especially the first message (in red) is worrysome: it appears that SSSD is not running.

- why is this caused by upgrading to 20.10?
- what can I do? I don't have an sssd.conf file in /etc/sssd but I am not sure why it has been removed or why it isn't present

As the journalctl file is about 8000 lines I only post the lines that signal the start of the sssd problems. If more info is needed please tell me.

```
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken sssd[1031]: SSSD couldn't load the configuration database [2]: No such file or directory.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken snapd[1030]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-pam.socket: Job sssd-pam.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-pam-priv.socket: Job sssd-pam-priv.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-nss.socket: Job sssd-nss.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-ssh.socket: Job sssd-ssh.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Job sssd-sudo.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-autofs.socket: Job sssd-autofs.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken systemd[1]: sssd-pac.socket: Job sssd-pac.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Nov 05 20:44:30 loosken dbus-daemon[995]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you need SSSD? If not, just remove it. Ordinary Ubuntu installations run without it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.10 sssd (System Security Services Daemon) failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288626/ubuntu-20-10-sssd-system-security-services-daemon-failure)

Comment: Other than the suggestions in the above link, I had the same issue in Ubuntu 20.10 and I simply removed `sssd` by `sudo apt purge sssd` because I don't need it.

Comment: Thank you all. As you all had (about) the same suggestion: remove it I did so and that worked. One wonders why a service was added that does not work and requires removal after having upgraded to 20.10. Anyway, I got an errorfree boot and that was what I wanted, Thanks!

Comment: just to add to the discussion, it's not only the upgrade. A whole new installation inside a VM with ZFS as a filesystem put it in place. Don't know if the ZFS parameters is relevant.

Comment: The first message says "SSSD couldn't load the configuration database [2]: No such file or directory." So, does the "/etc/sssd/sssd.conf" file exists? If not, you should create one as "root" with permission "0600".