# Ubuntu 20.10 System Security services are failing

Tags: security, services, 20.10, canonical-livepatch

Good morning,

$ **systemctl --failed**:

```
  UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION 
● fwupd-refresh.service                                 loaded failed failed Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd                               
● snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service loaded failed failed Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
● sssd.service                                          loaded failed failed System Security Services Daemon
```

$ **sudo systemctl status fwupd-refresh.service**:

```
● fwupd-refresh.service - Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-15 15:06:26 EET; 28min ago
       Docs: man:fwupdmgr(1)
   Main PID: 5120 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Dec 15 15:05:24 {NAME} systemd[1]: Starting Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd...
Dec 15 15:05:25 {NAME} fwupdmgr[5120]: Updating lvfs
Dec 15 15:06:26 {NAME} systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 15 15:06:26 {NAME} systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 15:06:26 {NAME} systemd[1]: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
```

$ **sudo systemctl status snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service**:

```
● snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service - Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-15 14:25:29 EET; 1h 12min ago
   Main PID: 2170 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Dec 15 14:25:29 {NAME} systemd[1]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Dec 15 14:25:29 {NAME} systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
Dec 15 14:25:29 {NAME} systemd[1]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 15 14:25:29 {NAME} systemd[1]: snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 14:25:29 {NAME} systemd[1]: Failed to start Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
```

$ **sudo systemctl status sssd.service**:

```
● sssd.service - System Security Services Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sssd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-15 14:25:21 EET; 1h 13min ago
   Main PID: 1760 (code=exited, status=4)
Dec 15 14:25:21 {NAME} systemd[1]: sssd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Dec 15 14:25:21 {NAME} systemd[1]: Stopped System Security Services Daemon.
Dec 15 14:25:21 {NAME} systemd[1]: sssd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 15 14:25:21 {NAME} systemd[1]: sssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 14:25:21 {NAME} systemd[1]: Failed to start System Security Services Daemon.
```

EDIT: just found the following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1288628/1067284) for sssd since I am using HDD not SSD... and Yes, I know 20.10 isn't LTS so I can't enjoy the livepatch but did the service fail for this reason?