# Sssd.service Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Problem

Tags: command-line, server, 20.04, sssd

I tried the installs on Ubuntu 18 and 16 Desktop and Server versions and it worked. I think the only problem is with ubuntu 20.04 Desktop. Device MacBook Pro 2015 13 inches.

```
Şub 12 17:16:35 User systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Job sssd-sudo.socket/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Şub 12 17:16:37 User systemd[1]: sssd-sudo.socket: Bound to unit sssd.service, but unit isn't active.
-- Subject: A start job for unit sssd-sudo.socket has failed
-- A start job for unit sssd-sudo.socket has finished with a failure.

systemctl restart sssd* --all
Failed to restart sssd-pac.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-pac.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-pac.service' for details.
Failed to restart sssd-sudo.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-sudo.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-sudo.service' for details.
Failed to restart sssd-nss.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-nss.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-nss.service' for details.
Failed to restart sssd-ssh.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-ssh.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-ssh.service' for details.
Failed to restart sssd-autofs.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-autofs.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-autofs.service' for details.
Failed to restart sssd-pam.service: Operation refused, unit sssd-pam.service may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status sssd-pam.service' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-nss.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-ssh.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-pam.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-pac.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-pam-priv.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-sudo.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
A dependency job for sssd-autofs.socket failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

Comment: As of just yesterday, I have the same problem on a 20.10 VM that worked fine last time. Upvoted.

Comment: Have you configured /etc/sssd/sssd.conf? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288626/ubuntu-20-10-sssd-system-security-services-daemon-failure

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. It is not related to the conf file

Comment: The problem persists when I discard or replace /etc/sssd/sssd.conf. But the service runs when the file is removed or the directory is empty.

Comment: When I try it on ubuntu 20.04 server it works. But desktop still fails.

Comment: Look at `sudo systemctl status sssd-sudo.socket` and `journalctl -xe` immediately after a start failure.

Answer (score 0):

It improved after reinstalling the operating system. Finally, I followed the steps here.
[Ubuntu 20.10 sssd (System Security Services Daemon) failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288626/ubuntu-20-10-sssd-system-security-services-daemon-failure)