# Dependency failed for SSSD Service responder socket

Tags: boot

In my boot.log, I have the following lines:

> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD…toFS Service responder socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD…vice responder private socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
> [DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.

What does it mean? I do not run SSHD service.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Trying again. I had my own brain fart...
SSSD is not SSHD. It's mostly used ime for integration with Windows domains.

Answer (score 0):

https://debugah.com/ubuntu-startup-error-demand-dependency-failed-for-sssd-22814/

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sssd/conf/sssd.conf /etc/sssd/.
sudo chmod 600 /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

Comment: Please don't tell somebody to blindly copy files without an explanation! Especially when the page you're citing doesn't explain it either (and that trailing `.` in the first line makes me think they didn't know what they were doing…). It's generally not a good idea to create a .conf file in a directory that contains a `.conf.d` — one expects the top level .conf files to be managed by apt, while the sysadmin can put local requirements in the .conf.d directory and not interfere with apt. This is a better link to the same info: https://askubuntu.com/a/1288628/25061