I can't get to a graphical login
Yesterday, I was trying to use my computer but a few seconds after I turned it on, I saw:

I have tried to fix it and I asked chatGPT, but I can't fix it.
I can only get to a  terminal with Alt+F2. I also tried all other Alt + F-key combinations, but none of them took me to a running GDM instance, they all took me to a command line login.
NEW UPDATE!!!
It's funny, but when I went to the computer repair shop and he tested my PC, it turned on without any errors. Even when I got home, the errors were gone. It's so weird

Hm can you Check If your Filesystem has enough free space? Have you tried to Boot Up the previous kernel?

Yes I do but nothing happend

Do I need to download again ubuntu and boot it?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288626/ubuntu-20-10-sssd-system-security-services-daemon-failure may help
